# Passing parameters to the View - From Grails to Javascript

Tags: javascript, grails

From my Controller i am passing a parameter to the view.

When i print the parameter from the Body it gets printed correctly. However, if i try to print the parameter from a Javascript function it doesn't work.

How can i correct this ?

Controller

```
def showpeople(Long id){
        def pInstance = People.get(id)
        render (view: "showpeople",model: [pInstance: pInstance])

    }
```

View

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var str = ${pInstance.stringval}; // <--- DOESN'T WORK  
alert (str); // <--- DOESN'T SHOW ALERT  

)}
</script>

<body>
${pInstance.stringval} <--- PRINTS SUCCESSFULLy 
</body>
```

Comment: `var str = '${pInstance.stringval}';` If it's a string you need to wrap it in quotes of some sort or the javascript will choke on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your alert doesn't show is you are outputting that value as a constant instead of a valid String within javascript. You really need to wrap it in quotes and you should also encode the string value for use with javascript.

For example:

```
var str = '${pInstance.stringval?.encodeAsJavaScript()}';
alert(str);
```